# AWS S3 Checksum values are null or pre-existing objects

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

If I upload a file to S3 using the following code, I will be able to retrieve its Checksum value later if needed.  Note, the variable “fileSHA256CheckSumValue” is the CheckSum value I generated from the file locally before I uploaded it.  When we do this, a CheckSum value is automatically generated for the file at S3 and compared with this value.  If they don’t match, it throws an exception and the file is not saved to S3.

[image]

Later, I can retrieve the file’s CheckSum value using this code:

[image]

I found that if I DON’T pass in the CheckSum value when uploading the file, I cannot retrieve it later:

[image]

In this case when I try to retrieve the CheckSum value, it returns null.

The problem is there are 1000s, maybe millions of files already in S3 that have not been uploaded with a CheckSum value passed in.  How can I force  a CheckSum value to be generated on these files?

I have googled this a lot and not found any posts or documentation regarding this.

Thank you.

Comment: S3 should generate an 'ETag' value for uploaded objects.  The value for the ETag should match the md5 for the uploaded object.  You should be able to get the ETag value from the object's S3 metadata.

Comment: @j_b : The ETag is a MD5 hash for a subset of S3 objects.  Any object uploaded using multi-part upload is a MD5 hash of the hashes of each part, and there's no way after the fact to know the size of the parts (though, you can guess most of the time)

Comment: @AnonCoward, good clarification. Adding a link to the documentation illustrating your point. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Object.html

Comment: Please don't use Images for showing code. It says its possible: *Object Upload – The newest versions of the AWS SDKs compute the specified checksum as part of the upload, and include it in an HTTP trailer at the conclusion of the upload. You also have the option to supply a precomputed checksum.* https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-additional-checksum-algorithms-for-amazon-s3/ - Use Postman to see the HTTP trailer, it'll be stashed in the response properties.

Comment: @AnonCoward,  Thank you all. I will not use images for code again. Everyone has provide helpful and good info, but I'm still not able to have a complete solution.
These are 3 scenarios I'm dealing with, #1 and #2 are good now, #3 still needs help.  I have searched like crazy and not found an answer yet.
1) upload from local (local to S3): can use checksum.
2) S3 to S3: use etag as the checksum may not exist
3) download S3 to local: I dont' know.  Can't use checksum since it may be null in S3.  Can't use etag because I can't generate in on local PC.
What can I do for #3?

Comment: You can attempt to calculate the [etag locally](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/b6d1b05c6371e2fd60c3f3655b06a36e).  It's not guaranteed, but in practice, it'll often be right.  If that's not good enough, you'll need to copy all of the objects from S3 to S3 with checksum256 enabled to pre-calc the sha256 for all objects.

Comment: Here's an [implementation in C#](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/7fce99c7d83002feee9eac9946223065)